# Prove a covariance matrix is positive semidefinite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

Given a random vector c with zero mean, the covariance matrix $\Sigma = E[cc^T]$. The following steps were given to prove that it is positive semidefinite.

$u^T\Sigma u = u^TE[cc^T]u = E[u^Tcc^Tu] = ||u^Tc|| \ge 0$

I don't understand how the expectation can equate to a norm.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/114072/321264

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Write instead
$$
u^T\Sigma u = u^TE[cc^T]u = E[u^Tcc^Tu] = E[\|c^Tu\|^2] \ge 0.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that for any vector $v,w$, the dot product is given by $v \cdot w = v^Tw$.  Thus, we have
$$
E[u^Tcc^Tu] = E[(u^Tc)(c^Tu)] = E[(u \cdot c)(c \cdot u)] = 
E[|u \cdot c|^2] \geq 0
$$
I'm not quite sure what they meant with the norm.