# Why do the following facts implies that the cov matrix is PSD. Is anyone willing to help?

Tags: calculus, probability, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus

Let $V=(v_{ij})$ be a covariance matrix associated to the random vector r.

> My professor writes that the covariance matrix is PSD. Indeed for all
>   $i,j = 1,...,n$ we have $v_{ij} = E((r_i −E(r_i))(r_j −E(r_j))$ so,
>   calling $ρ_{ij} := \frac{ v_{ij}}  {\sqrt{v_{ii}v_{jj}}}$, ($ρ_{ij}$
>   is called correlation of $r_i$ and $r_j$) we get $ρ_{ij}≤ |1|$. The
>   two above facts imply V is PSD.

But why do the above two facts implies that the matrix is PSD?? Is anyone willing to help??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the proof that covariance matrices are always semi-definite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114072/what-is-the-proof-that-covariance-matrices-are-always-semi-definite)

Comment: I do not think so. I mean, it does not use the  facts mentioned

Comment: Isn't the first fact alone enough?

Comment: It is true the that the second fact (correlation coefficient) in effect gives you PSD for a 2x2 matrix (i.e. in effect via Sylvester Determinant Criterion noting that top left component is positive).  The n x n case comes from the first fact alone.  Consider centered random vector $A := r - E[r]$.  For $\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^n$, the covariance matrix obeys  $\mathbf x^T \operatorname E(A A^\top) \mathbf x  = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n x_i x_j E[A_i A_j] =  E[\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n x_i x_j A_i A_j] = E[(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i A_i)^2]\geq 0$  and hence is PSD

Comment: What he might  mean is: Covariance $\Rightarrow$ PSD $\Rightarrow$ $|\rho_{ij}|\le 1$. The implications are not reversable.

Comment: Well symmetry is pretty easy. Did you figure that out?

Comment: Yes, sure. I figured out symmetry